# Unable to install react-navigation package using npm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo

I'am building an app with expo. I want to use react-navigation to be able to navigate between screens.

But i am having trouble installing the package. Actually I have this issue with every single package I am trying to install...

By running the installation script :

npm install --save react-navigation

I have these warnings and I am not able to import the package in my project :

```js
npm WARN expo-google-sign-in@2.0.0 requires a peer of react-native@^0.55.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.11 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-alpha.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.11 requires a peer of react-native@^0.44.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN url-loader@1.1.2 requires a peer of webpack@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

The terminal error ouptu is :

```html
While trying to resolve module `react-navigation` from file 
`/app/App.js`, the package `/app/node_modules/reactnavigation/package.json` 
was successfully found. 
However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved 
(`/app/node_modules/react-navigation/src/react-navigation.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
[13:58:26] 
[13:58:26]   * `/app/node_modules/react-navigation/src/react-navigation.js(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
[13:58:26]   * `/app/node_modules/react-navigation/src/react-navigation.js/index(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
```

I have this issue every time a try to install a package. I didn't find any solution that works for me.

Comment: Hmm... Might be an issue with your npm installation if it's never working. Maybe try installing yarn, it's also a node package manager and operates very similarly. Some people even prefer it, it has some benefits like faster installation speed by doing stuff like caching. Give it a try and see if it fixes your problem: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#arch-stable

Comment: Make sure your node_modules folder, and its children folders, are not owned by root. Which OS are you on?

Comment: Can you share a git repository and share your code. I have a feeling that you might be doing something wrong while installing npm packages. 
Also, Try removing/deleting npm module folder, go to your root folder (having your package.json file), do `npm install`.

Comment: I tried installing the package with yarn and it worked. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

If you still have that problem try react-navigation 2.0 instead. Latest versions are not always the most stable ones

Comment: This is meant to be a comment. Just because you don't have enough points doesn't mean you can post something which should be a comment. 
Also, Since you are a new contributor, Welcome to StackOverflow community :)

Comment: I am sorry. As you have mentioned, I am a new member so I am still learning.

Comment: You are a champ. Just wanted to mention this for future :)